# how to convert python __len__() into java

Tags: java, python

i have been working on converting a python code to java related to my research work, i have a query in Python **len**() object. my problem is in [::-1] as the code provided.

i have tried to do it in java by simply an incremental loop but it does not work. it gives array out of bound exception at temp_line.split('$target/')[1].

```
 for i in range(0, script_lines.__len__())[::-1]:
   temp_line = script_lines[i]
        if "$target/" in temp_line and "cp" in temp_line:
           Case_num = 1 + int(temp_line.split('$target/')[1].split('.txt')[0])
            return Case_num
```

i want to know what does [::-1] mean in the code so i can convert it to java.

Comment: you want to convert code, of which you don't know what it does, to a different language? why? and how would you test it? first learn what it does, then think about converting it

Comment: Stultuske sir i have a code more than two thousand lines and i have have already converted it, trying to process the data, i am stuck there from so many days and cannot find the solution thats why asking here. i know what do my code do.. just some programming problems because i am a beginner in both java and python.

Comment: you stated you don't know what the original code does, how were you imagining to convert it (correctly)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[::-1]` in Python means "all elements of the sequence `x` starting from the last one, ending with the first one). `range(y)` generates all numbers from `0` to `y - 1`. Thus, your line will produce indices starting with the last index of `script_lines` to 0.

It is not great Python code though - it creates a list where one is not needed. Using `__len__` method is also frowned upon, as a plumbing method; rather use the porcelain `len` function. A better way to write it would have been

```
for i in range(len(script_lines) - 1, -1, -1):
```

(Start at `length - 1`, stop before reaching `-1` while adding `-1` each iteration.) But since `i` is actually never mentioned after fetching `temp_line`, the even better rewrite would be

```
for temp_line in reversed(script_lines):
```

Java doesn't have anything like `reversed`, so you'll have to use a loop over the indices:

```
for (int i = scriptLines.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a python **extended slice**.

For example, you can extract the elements of a list that have even indexes:

```
>>> L = range(10)
>>> L[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Negative values also work to make a copy of the same list in reverse order:

```
>>> L[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

This also works for tuples, arrays, and strings:

```
>>> s='abcd'
>>> s[::2]
'ac'
>>> s[::-1]
'dcba'
```

See more details at https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/